# How can I add multiple path for home page with react router dom 6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using react router dom 6

I want to load Login component for 3 paths:

`/ & /login & /home`

I tried by this path:

`<Route path='/(home|login)/' element={<Login />} />`

but it doesn't work...

Comment: In RRDv6 each route's `path` prop takes one string path. You'll just need to declare multiple routes.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way:

```
<Route path='/' element={<Login />} />
<Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
<Route path='/home' element={<Login />} />
```

Answer (score 4):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `Route` component's `path` prop takes only a single string path value, not an array like previous versions did.

[Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route)

> ```
> declare function Route(
>   props: RouteProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactElement | null;
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string; // <-- string type only
> }
> ```

You will need to render individual routes for each path.

```
<Route path='/' element={<Login />} />
<Route path='/home' element={<Login />} />
<Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
```

Or abstract this utility into a ***function*** (*not a component!*). It needs to be a function call as only `Route` or `React.Fragment` components are valid children of the `Routes` component.

```
const renderPaths = (paths, Element) =>
  paths.map((path) => <Route key={path} path={path} element={Element} />);
```

...

```
<Routes>
  {renderPaths(["/", "/home", "/login"], <Login />)}
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-add-multiple-path-for-home-page-with-react-router-dom-6]

Comment: I think this message (changes from v6) needs to be emphasized.  Best explanation by far.

Answer (score 2):

Latest versions of React Router accepts an array of strings as path for an `<Route/>`.

You can use

```
<Route path={['/', '/login', '/home']}  element={<Login />} />
```

Reference: https://v5.reactrouter.com/core/api/Route/path-string-string

Comment: OP is looking for answer in RRDv6, this won't work.

Comment: Thanks but i'm using v6

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<Route path={['/', '/login', '/home']} element={<Login />} />
```

Comment: OP is looking for answer in RRDv6, this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Not a react pro, but I believe it can be achieved through components.

1. Create one home component/page.
2. in your route '/', 'login' or 'home' call that page/component.

> ```
> <Route path="/" element={<YourComponent />} />
>
> <Route path="/login" element={<YourComponent />} />
>
> <Route path="/home" element={<YourComponent />} />
> ```